# Check if values in a list exisiting in another list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

---

I want to check if the list in `Column A` contains only products from the list in `Column B`.

If yes in `Cell D1` the value = `yes` 
If not in `Cell D1` the value = `no`

As cou can see in the example above `Product C` and `Product E` do not exist in the list in `Column B`, therefore the value in `Cell D1` is `no`.

---

So far I was able to figure out this formula `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1;$B$1:$B$5;1;0));"No";"Yes")`. 
However, I would have to add a helper column with this formula to each row next to `Column A`.

Is there a solution that solves the issue with one formula in in `Cell D1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic formula might be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,B1:B10))=COUNTA(A1:A10)
```

or more dynamic

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A:A,B1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))))=COUNTA(A:A)
```

[image]

[image]

These can be wrapped in an if statement to give "yes" or "no":

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,B1:B10))=COUNTA(A1:A10),"yes","no")

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A:A,B1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))))=COUNTA(A:A),"yes","no")
```